# how to show unlimited posts on wordpress search page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've wordpress website where on search page unlimited posts needs to be shown without any pagination. I have tried changing the parameter in Wordpress admin which shows the number of posts from the limit mentioned under settings.

I tried using `$wpdb->query` function but it didn't worked as have custom post types in query string.

```
<?php $posts=query_posts($query_string . '&posts_per_page=-1'); ?>
```

Comment: What have you tried? You have to show some code for us to help you. Considering you have 1K+ reputation you should know how to ask a question. Have you tried searching [here](https://wordpress.org/support/) or asking [here](https://en.forums.wordpress.com/)?

Comment: I didn't asked the `support` coz was looking for quick help here.

Comment: This is not how SO works, please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Script47 Can you help answering the question ? I am not looking for some reputation out of this question. It was kind of urgent and new to wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the query at search page by this hook.

```
function search_filter($query) {
  if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
      $query->set('posts_per_page', -1);
    }
  }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts','search_filter');
```